# C# Speech To Text with Google API

Tags: c#, google-speech-to-text-api

I want to convert speech to text using Google Api 'speech-to-text'.
it worked when I took the example file but doesn't when I choose a file from local

that's my code:

```
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;

namespace SpeechToTextApiDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var config = new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = LanguageCodes.Hebrew.Israel,
                EnableWordTimeOffsets = true
            };
            var audio = RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri("gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac");

            var response = speech.Recognize(config, audio);

            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Transcript: { alternative.Transcript}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Word details:");
                    Console.WriteLine($" Word count:{alternative.Words.Count}");
                    foreach (var item in alternative.Words)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"  {item.Word}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"    WordStartTime: {item.StartTime}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"    WordEndTime: {item.EndTime}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you tell more about this file? How many MB/KB it has? From your code I can see that you are using FLAC format from Google Cloud Storage. So I assume this worked and now you want to use also FLAC file from your local machine? When your audio file is longer than 60 seconds you should use GCS. Is this the same file from your local machine which was used in test from GCS? Did you get any error log?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#speech_requests

- You first need to upload the file to a storage bucket and pass that gs:// link and use either the Asynchronous or Synchronous API.
- You need to rewrite your code to use the Streaming API, that way you can stream your file and do not need to upload it first.